# Get string union, dynamically from array

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this:

```
const goodKeys = {
  'integer': 1,
  'string': 1,
  'number': 1,
  'function': 1,
  'boolean': 1,
  'null': 1,
  'undefined': 1,
  'symbol': 1
};
```

And I am looking to extrace/derive the following from the above dynamically:

```
export type OptsKey =
  'integer' |
  'string' |
  'number' |
  'function' |
  'boolean' |
  'null' |
  'undefined' |
  'symbol';
```

I tried doing this:

```
const keys = Object.keys(goodKeys);

export interface OptsKeys {
  [key: string]: typeof keys
}
```

but that doesn't work and even if it did, it's unlikely it would resolve to the a union of strings instead just an array.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I guess TS can check if a string value matches one of those in the union? Maybe not, maybe I need to use an `enum` instead.

Comment: You just want a type that represents all the keys of the const? `keyof typeof goodKeys`?

Comment: I didn't know there was a `keyof` operator, that might be what I am looking for

Comment: what I am prob looking for is `[key: string]: keyof goodKeys`

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you are trying to check which of the object keys has 1 as value, right?

```
const goodKeys = {
  'integer': 1,
  'string': 0,
  'number': 1,
  'function': 0,
  'boolean': 1,
  'null': 0,
  'undefined': 1,
  'symbol': 1
};

const transform = myObject => {
    const result = [];
    for(const key in myObject) {
       if(myObject[key]) result.push(key);
    }
    return result;
}

const myArray = transform(goodKeys);
console.log(myArray)
// [ 'integer', 'number', 'boolean', 'undefined', 'symbol' ]
```